# Using cpanm with Module::Install instead of CPAN or CPANPLUS

Tags: perl, dependencies, makefile, perl-module

I am experiencing some frustration right now with installing dependencies from CPAN (trying to write an installation script that works under local::lib). This may be overkill but my code for the Makefile is this...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use inc::Module::Install;

name 'Statcounts';
all_from 'lib/Statcounts.pm';

requires 'Catalyst::Runtime' => '5.80007';
requires 'Catalyst::Plugin::ConfigLoader';
requires 'Catalyst::Plugin::Static::Simple';
requires 'Catalyst::Action::RenderView';
requires 'Catalyst::ScriptRunner';

requires 'parent';
requires 'Config::General'; # This should reflect the config file format you've chosen
             # See Catalyst::Plugin::ConfigLoader for supported formats
catalyst_par_classes('Catalyst::ScriptRunner');

catalyst;

install_script glob('script/*.pl');
auto_install;

WriteAll;
```

perl Makefile.PL works fine. Problem is when I'm running

```
make installdeps
```

I still get prompted with

```
Shall I follow them and prepend them to the queue
of modules we are processing right now? [yes]
```

I simply want a cpanminus like way to install the deps without all the prompting. I'm not aware that Module::Install even supports cpanm.

Does anyone have a clue as to how I get make installdeps to install all the deps in the same easy way that cpanm does?

Thank you so much in advance.
Janie

Comment: `cpanm --installdeps .`

Comment: Brad, you are a saint! You have saved what little hair I have left. JW

Answer (score 1):

(Question answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

@Brad Gilbert tersely wrote:

> `cpanm --installdeps`